# localStorage sets value in one key all the time

Tags: local-storage

I created a function that sets a data- attribute into localStorage. But it only sets the value in the same key all the time, resulting in only one key. How to solve this.

Comment: Please provide more information. Its probably wrong code that gives these error.

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code. Without the code, we *can't* reproduce your problem, and hence, we cannot solve your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A simple localStorage example is given below.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('All assets are loaded');
  localStorage.clear();
})

function fun(id) {
  localStorage.setItem(id.getAttribute('data-date'), "tasks from " + id.getAttribute('data-date'));
  var x = localStorage.getItem(id.getAttribute('data-date'));
  document.getElementById("pop").innerHTML = x;
  console.log(id.getAttribute('data-date'));
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " HAS " + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.644);
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a {
  padding: 4vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" onclick="fun(this)" data-date="1">1st day</div>
<div class="a" onclick="fun(this)" data-date="2">2nd day</div>
<div class="a" onclick="fun(this)" data-date="3">3rd day</div>
<div>inside the popup: </div>
<div id='pop'>tasks comes here </div>
```

If every value goes into the same key, you probably haven't read the unique data- attribute from the element within your function.